# Proxmox VM disk file is bigger than provisioned setting

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, proxmox

I'm looking into one Proxmox server that is running out of space. It has some over provisioned storage. Everything looks to be fine except one VM disk. It is 10 GB disk according to configuration but the file itself on Proxmox is 15 GB big. I'm mostly using vmware and never seen such thing before.

*Can someone tell why it is like that?*

Is it the way Proxmox stores snapshots (this VM had one that was removed)? Or maybe it was resized?

I'm a bit worried for other VM disks.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

I had to migrate that disk to different storage. Disk file size become 10 GB big after this procedure.

Comment: That's not really an answer though. The question "Is it the way Proxmox stores snapshots (this VM had one that was removed)? Or maybe it was resized?"